# Casting type twice necessary in a generic class method return call

Tags: c#, inheritance, covariance

I have a case where I have a generic class and I want a method that returns a newly created object of the same type and the instance of the class. I was running into an error that in the end I was able to solve using a double-cast

```
return  (T) (A) new B(1, true);
```

if I used simple

```
return  (T) new B(1, true);
```

instead, it fails, unable to cast B to T. Full code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace Tests;

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestInheritance
    {
        private class A
        {
            private int _a;
            
            public A(int a)
                => _a = a;
        }
    
        private class B : A
        {
            private bool _b;
            
            public B(int a, bool b) : base(a)
                => _b = b;
        }
    
        private class MyClass<T> where T : A
        {
            public T? GetElem()
            {
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
                {
                    return (T) new A(1);
                }
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
                {
                    // Works
                    return  (T) (A) new B(1, true);
                    // Does not work
                    return (T) new B(1, true);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    
        [Test]
        public void TestClass()
        {
            var myA = new MyClass<A>();
            var elemA = myA.GetElem();
            var myB = new MyClass<B>();
            var elemB = myB.GetElem();
            
            Assert.NotNull(elemA);
            Assert.AreEqual(elemA.GetType(), typeof(A));
            Assert.NotNull(elemB);
            Assert.AreEqual(elemB.GetType(), typeof(B));
        }
    }
```

The error is

> TestInheritance.cs(39, 24): [CS0030] Cannot convert type 'Tests.TestInheritance.B' to 'T'

The question is why I can cast B -> A -> T, but not B -> T?

Target framework is .net6

Comment: Presumably because the compiler does not know whether `T` is a type that `B` can convert to - e.g.: you could have a different  `class C : A` and try `MyClass<C>`

Comment: The compiler only knows that `T:A` and `B:A`. That doesn't imply that `B:T`. Dogs and Frogs are both Animals but that doesn't imply that Poodle is a Frog. That's the reason you need all those casts. You're effectively trying to write `return  (Frog) (Animal) new Poodle(1, true);`. That's not safe

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is there a type-safe version of doing this? Basically I just want my class to be able to internally instantiate objects of its type.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you find yourself writing `typeof(T)` in a generic class then your whole design is broken. Perhaps `MyClass` should accept a `Func<T>` in its constructor which gives it a way of generating new `T` for whichever is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual compiler error has been explained already: `T` is an `A`, but `B` might not be a `T`. the `typeof` does not help the compiler in this regard.

**Rule of thumb:** if you find yourself writing `typeof(T)` in a generic class then your whole design is broken.

Perhaps `MyClass` should accept a `Func<T>` in its constructor or in a static field which gives it a way of generating `new T` for whichever `T` is specified.

```
    private class MyClass<T> where T : A
    {
        public static Func<T> DefaultValueFactory { get; set; }

        public T? GetElem()
        {
            if (DefaultValueFactory == null)
                return default;
            return DefaultValueFactory();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestClass()
    {
        MyClass<A>.DefaultValuefactory => new A(1);
        MyClass<B>.DefaultValuefactory => new B(1, true);
        var myA = new MyClass<A>();
        var elemA = myA.GetElem();
        var myB = new MyClass<B>();
        var elemB = myB.GetElem();
        
        Assert.NotNull(elemA);
        Assert.AreEqual(elemA.GetType(), typeof(A));
        Assert.NotNull(elemB);
        Assert.AreEqual(elemB.GetType(), typeof(B));
    }
```

The point is that `MyClass<T>`, being generic, does not *know* anything about `T` other than it is or derives from `A`. It has no idea how to construct it, and must be given a way to do so.

Note that at this point the whole test case `Assert.AreEqual(elemA.GetType(), typeof(A));` makes no sense, as there is no way you could get the wrong type. You could only get a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

T is an A.
B is an A.

B can be cast to A because Bs are As.
A can be cast to T because Ts are As.

You cannot cast B to T directly because Bs are not necessarily Ts. That is an assumption.

Instead of this:

```
 return (T) new B(1, true);
```

You can do this:

```
var bAsT = new B(1, true) as T;
return bAsT;
```

bAsT will be null if B(1, true) is not a T, and therefore the compiler will accept it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/safely-cast-using-pattern-matching-is-and-as-operators